# jQuery .load() does not works properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this 2 pages [German](http://birsmatt.ch/wohnungen/) and [English](http://birsmatt.ch/wohnungen-en/)  with a table that is similar in both pages.
To have the same table i used this `<script>` to load it in both pages:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#table_en').load('http://birsmatt.ch/wohnungen/ #table');
});
</script>
```

The table should be animated via javascript and it works in the German page as you can see going with the mouse over the table's rows, but this animation does not works in the English page.

How can i fix it?

EDIT: (Table's Animation `<script>`)

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.row1').hover(function() {
$('.one').toggle();
});

$('.row2').hover(function() {
  $('.two').toggle();
});

$('.row3').hover(function() {
  $('.tree').toggle();
}); 

$('.row4').hover(function() {
  $('.four').toggle();
}); 

$('.row5').hover(function() {
  $('.five').toggle();
});

$('.row6').hover(function() {
  $('.six').toggle();
});

$('.row7').hover(function() {
  $('.seven').toggle();
});

 $('.row8').hover(function() {
  $('.eight').toggle();
});

 $('.row9').hover(function() {
  $('.nine').toggle();
}); 

$('.row10').hover(function() {
  $('.ten').toggle();
});

$('.row11').hover(function() {
  $('.eleven').toggle();
});

$('.row12').hover(function() {
  $('.twelve').toggle();
}); 

$('.row13').hover(function() {
  $('.thirteen').toggle();
});     

$('.row14').hover(function() {
  $('.quattordici').toggle();
});    

 $('.row15').hover(function() {
  $('.quindici').toggle();
});    

 $('.row16').hover(function() {
 $('.sedici').toggle();
});

 $('.row17').hover(function() {
 $('.diciassette').toggle();
}); 

 $('.row18').hover(function() {
 $('.diciotto').toggle();
});  

 $('.row19').hover(function() {
 $('.diciannove').toggle();
});

 $('.row20').hover(function() {
 $('.venti').toggle();
});

 $('.row21').hover(function() {
 $('.ventuno').toggle();
}); 

$('.row22').hover(function() {
 $('.ventidue').toggle();
});   

$('.row23').hover(function() {
 $('.ventitre').toggle();
}); 

$('.row24').hover(function() {
 $('.ventiquattro').toggle();
});

$('.row25').hover(function() {
 $('.venticinque').toggle();
});

$('.row26').hover(function() {
 $('.ventisei').toggle();
});

$('.row27').hover(function() {
  $('.ventisette').toggle();
}); 

$('.row28').hover(function() {
  $('.ventotto').toggle();
});

$('.row29').hover(function() {
  $('.ventinove').toggle();
});

$('.row30').hover(function() {
  $('.trenta').toggle();
});

$('.row31').hover(function() {
  $('.trentuno').toggle();
});

$('.row32').hover(function() {
  $('.trentadue').toggle();
});

$('.row33').hover(function() {
  $('.trentatre').toggle();
});

$('.row34').hover(function() {
  $('.trentaquattro').toggle();
});

 $('.row35').hover(function() {
  $('.trentacinque').toggle();
}); 

$('.row36').hover(function() {
  $('.trentasei').toggle();
});

$('.row37').hover(function() {
  $('.trentasette').toggle();
});

$('.row38').hover(function() {
  $('.trentotto').toggle();
});

$('.row39').hover(function() {
  $('.trentanove').toggle();
});

$('.row40').hover(function() {
  $('.quaranta').toggle();
});

$('.row41').hover(function() {
  $('.quarantuno').toggle();
});

$('.row42').hover(function() {
  $('.quarantadue').toggle();
});

$('.row43').hover(function() {
  $('.quarantatre').toggle();
});

$('.row44').hover(function() {
  $('.quarantaquattro').toggle();
});

$('.row45').hover(function() {
  $('.quarantacinque').toggle();
});

$('.row46').hover(function() {
  $('.quarantasei').toggle();
});

$('.row47').hover(function() {
  $('.quarantasette').toggle();
});

$('.row48').hover(function() {
  $('.quarantotto').toggle();
});

$('.row49').hover(function() {
  $('.quarantanove').toggle();
});

$('.row50').hover(function() {
  $('.cinquanta').toggle();
});

$('.row51').hover(function() {
  $('.cinquantuno').toggle();
});

$('.row52').hover(function() {
  $('.cinquantadue').toggle();
});

$('.row53').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_1').toggle();
});

$('.row54').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_2').toggle();
});

$('.row55').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_3').toggle();
});

$('.row56').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_4').toggle();
});

$('.row57').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_5').toggle();
});

$('.row58').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_6').toggle();
});

$('.row59').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_7').toggle();
});

$('.row60').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_8').toggle();
});

$('.row61').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_9').toggle();
});

$('.row62').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_10').toggle();
});

$('.row63').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_11').toggle();
});

$('.row64').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_12').toggle();
});

$('.row65').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_13').toggle();
});

$('.row66').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_14').toggle();
});

$('.row67').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_15').toggle();
});

$('.row68').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_16').toggle();
});

$('.row69').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_17').toggle();
});

$('.row70').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_18').toggle();
});

$('.row71').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_19').toggle();
});

$('.row72').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_20').toggle();
});

$('.row73').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_21').toggle();
});

$('.row74').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_22').toggle();
});

$('.row75').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_23').toggle();
});

$('.row76').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_24').toggle();
});

$('.row77').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_25').toggle();
});

$('.row78').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_26').toggle();
});

$('.row79').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_27').toggle();
});

$('.row80').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_28').toggle();
});

$('.row81').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_29').toggle();
});

$('.row82').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_30').toggle();
});        

$('.row83').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_31').toggle();
});

$('.row84').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_32').toggle();
}); 

$('.row85').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_33').toggle();
});

$('.row86').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_34').toggle();
});

$('.row87').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_35').toggle();
});

$('.row88').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_36').toggle();
});

$('.row89').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_37').toggle();
});

$('.row90').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_38').toggle();
});

$('.row91').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_39').toggle();
});

$('.row92').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_40').toggle();
});

$('.row93').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_41').toggle();
});

$('.row94').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_42').toggle();
});

$('.row95').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_43').toggle();
});

$('.row96').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_44').toggle();
});

$('.row97').hover(function() {
  $('.hause2_45').toggle();
});        
});
</script>
```

Comment: *"i used this `<script>` to load it in both pages"* Really? You have a `table_en` element on the German page?

Comment: Your English page throws this error: "birsmatt.ch/:786 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: @T.J.Crowder to be honest i am loading in `#table_en` the `#table`... Did you read my question? ._.

Comment: @MarioGarcia any ideas to fix it?

Comment: @ACrazyDevelop: There's no call to be rude. Yes, I read the question. And I read the code. The code looks for a `#table_en` element on the page and loads `#table` from the URL into it. So I asked you if you really had a `#table_en` on your German page.

Comment: We will need more info of your code to help you....

Comment: @MarioGarcia i cannot copy the entire javascript code cause the reputation :/ if you inspect the website you can see it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry maybe i was rude, but i'm not :) anyway the `#table` ID is an ID that i used to call the "General table" and i simply want to load this "General table" into the English page `<div>` that has as ID `#table_en`. I am able to load it but not able to load the other javascript code.

Comment: @ACrazyDevelop: Even with a rep of 1 you can put a [mcve] in the question. Sadly it can't be a runnable one (since you can't do the `load` part), but that doesn't stop you from doing the MCVE.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder edited the first post with the `<script>` i am using to animate the table.

Comment: I realized that with what you're doing, event delegation would be a better approach than my original answer, so I've added that.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code in the question, it doesn't work because the table doesn't exist as of when you try to hook the events to animate it. You have code running in response to `ready`, but the `load` call is *asynchronous*, so the table won't be there yet.

Move your various `hover` calls into a named function, and call it from the `load` callback. You may need to target them more carefully to avoid hooking the events twice on other tables (if other tables use those classes).

Here's a simplified example, using `setTimeout` to simulate the `load`'s asynchronicity:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  function hookEvents(scope) {
    $(scope).find(".row1").hover(
      // Just for the purposes of the example; if it were just
      // styling, we'd use CSS, not JavaScript
      function() {
        $(this).addClass("hovering");
      },
      function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hovering");
      }
    );
  }
  
  // Hook the animations up to any existing tables
  hookEvents(document.body);
  
  // Do the "load"
  setTimeout(function() {
    // (This is the load callback)
    $("#table_en").append(
      '<table><tbody><tr class="row1"><td>Dyanmically added</td></tr></tbody></table>'
    );
    
    // Hook events on the newly-installed table
    hookEvents("#table_en");
  }, 250);
});
```

```css
table, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 4px;
}
.hovering {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Existing table unrelated to #table_en:
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="row1">
        <td>Existing table</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<dvi>
  table_en:
  <div id="table_en"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...although having said that, there's a simpler solution: *Event delegation*. jQuery's `hover` is really just a convenience method for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, which jQuery also makes bubble (even though they don't natively), but in a useful way.

So we can change

```
$('.row1').hover(function() {
    $('.one').toggle();
});
```

to

```
$(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".row1", function() {
    $('.one').toggle();
});
```

jQuery will call the handler when the mouse enters or leaves an element with class `row1`, even if the element wasn't on the page when that code was run, because the handler is *actually* attached to `document.body`, not `.row1`, jQuery just filters things for us.

So here's that example, but simpler:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".row1", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hovering");
  });
  
  // Do the "load"
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#table_en").append(
      '<table><tbody><tr class="row1"><td>Dyanmically added</td></tr></tbody></table>'
    );
  }, 250);
});
```

```css
table, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 4px;
}
.hovering {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Existing table unrelated to #table_en:
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="row1">
        <td>Existing table</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<dvi>
  table_en:
  <div id="table_en"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: Whenever you find yourself repeating code like that, it probably means you can refactor it to be simpler. In this case, there are two ways you can do that (at least):

1. You could make the selector a `data-*` attribute on the row:

   ```
   <!-- Instead of row1 -->
   <tr class="row" data-animate=".one">...</tr>
   <!-- Instead of row2 -->
   <tr class="row" data-animate=".two">...</tr>
   ```

   ...and then a single handler:

   ```
   $(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".row", function() {
       var sel = $(this).attr("data-animate");
       $(sel).toggle();
   });
   ```
2. If you don't want to change the markup, have a lookup table instead:

   ```
   var animate = {
       row1: ".one",
       row2: ".two",
       // ...
   };
   ```

   ...and then a single handler:

   ```
   // This creates a string like ".row1, .row2, .row3" and so on
   var rowSelector = "." + Object.keys(animate).join(", .");
   $(document.body).on("mouseenter mouseleave", rowSelector, function() {
       var sel = animate[this.className]; // Assumes the rows don't have other classes
       $(sel).toggle();
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you, this works now!! I have another question about the checkboxes: In the German page when you check a  box in the dropdown menu automatically display the dedicated row 
`$("#checkboxID").change(function(){
 $("#tableID tr.rowEG").toggle(!this.checked); ` but dis does not works in english. Any ideas?

Comment: @ACrazyDevelop: It's the same problem: The code trying to hook up that event handler is doing so before the element exists, so the event doesn't get hooked. Same solution: Use delegation (or hook the events after the table is loaded).

Comment: I'm trying with `$(document.body).change("mouseclick", "#checkboxID", function() {
    $("#tableID tr.rowEG").toggle(!this.checked); ` but maybe is not the right syntax isn't it?

Comment: @ACrazyDevelop: `.change` is a shortcut for `.on("change", `, you don't want to use that if you're hooking up a click. Also, it's `click`, not `mouseclick`.

Comment: Thank you so much... also solved. Now last question is: how can i fix the header? This script does not works in the English page:
`<script>
    document.getElementById("wrap").addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    var translate = "translate(0," + this.scrollTop + "px)";
    this.querySelector("thead").style.transform = translate;
});
    </script>`

Comment: @ACrazyDevelop: You might want to post that separately, looks like a completely different problem. SO questions aren't meant to be moving targets.

Answer (score 0):

Your `jQuery(document).ready(function($){}` is not being fired or it's being fired too early. Try to wrap all that code in a function and call it when you are sure that your rows have been loaded.

Right now, if I write in the console:

```
 $('.row1').hover(function() {
      $('.one').toggle();
    });
```

It starts workig for the first row, so just make sure that this code is being executed after your table is loaded.

Try that.

Comment: What do you mean for "Try to wrap all that code in a function and call it when you are sure that your rows have been loaded."

Comment: Put it inside a custom function, and call it after the table has finished loading. T.J. Crowder gives a better explanation, same answer tho